# Is there any method in flutter with INTL package to convert this date format in DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, intl, flutter-intl

I am developing a flutter news app. The format of date from Api response is ( 2021-02-05T09:41:13+0000 ) and I want to convert it to DD-MM-YYYY format. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
return formatted;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String date = DateFormat.yMd().format('your date here');
```